# Why does Opera resize email input fields?

Tags: html, css, opera

Here is my code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfn4c/1/).

I've tested this in the latest versions of Chrome, Opera, FF, and Safari. All seems to appear fine except Opera. It seems as if Opera resizes the email input field because when I change it to text, it works out just fine. Is there a fix for this?

**EDIT:** Using Opera v11.01 on Mac OS X 10.6.7

Comment: @Shakti, Woops. Forgot that detail. Updated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything that says that the default style for an email input should have the same width as the default style for a text input, and you're not explicitly asking for anything other than the browser's default style.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Tyler - you're asking for one of two different types of controls to appear on the rendered page, and you've not specified what width you want the control to be. It would appear that the default stylesheet for Opera uses a different width for email controls than for text controls.

Comment: Oh, okay I misunderstood (a.k.a. didn't really think about) what you said. I set the width attributes equal to each other and it works great now. Thanks. :)